# How to forecast time series model using classical machine learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I just started to learn time series (about time after avoiding it for very long).

I read through some short summaries and jumped straight to see if one can model time series using supervised learning, turns out there's 2 ways.

The way I want to ask is based on the famous [Kaggle notebook on XGboost for Time Series](https://www.kaggle.com/code/robikscube/tutorial-time-series-forecasting-with-xgboost). The notebook is clear and one see that he transformed (decomposed) each datetime record to its week, day, month etc to somewhat capture trends/seasonal.

A short pseudo code is below:

```py
def create_features(df, label=None):
    """
    Creates time series features from datetime index
    """
    df['date'] = df.index
    df['hour'] = df['date'].dt.hour
    ...
    
    X = df[['hour','dayofweek','quarter','month','year',
           'dayofyear','dayofmonth','weekofyear']]
    return ...
```

Now I tried it myself on a dataset, works fine and predictions made on **Unseen Test Set** is decent. I thought it's all good and tried to make more features, especially features like `rolling mean`, `rolling median` over past timeperiods and soon I ran into a big issue. During training and validation, we **have the target values** and hence these `rolling` or `lag` features can be found. But on unseen test set, there should be no target for us to model...how then should we go about forecasting, say 3 days ahead? Note that I did not notice this because the initial features are agnostic of target, as long as we have a datetime, we can create these features.

I hope someone can guide me to some good tutorials on this. I read [the de-facto tutorials here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/) but he is using the other way to model time series as supervised.

Comment: Hi @nan. I come from a slightly different background with classical time series (TS) learning first, and learning machine learning (ML) later for some side projects. All I would say is that with ML, it is often implied that your data is IID; but TS data is explicitly non-IID. So, you have to ensure your data is suitably transformed to uphold the IID/stationarity type conditions. I would say many ML tutorials overlook these types of preliminaries, and the requirements for out-of-sample TS forecasts/predictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rolling mean or lagged target values will always belong to past. If you plan to predict $t+k$ from up to day $t$ features, the rolling mean, however long it is, should contain the mean of the target values until day $t$.

At any arbitrary time $t$ in the test set, you can assume you have the data available until (and including) day $t-k$; even if day $t-k$ is in the test set. You should preprocess your test set accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and soon ran into a problem, let's say I have a feature called 6-hours lag, then if at time t = 1am, we can forecast 7am since we do have t's value, but we cannot forecast 8am since we do not know 2am's value. I need to be able to forecast more than 1 step ahead, is recursive-multistep a recommended way?

Comment: If you want to extrapolate, yes, that is certainly an option. This means the problem is not just predicting $k$ time ahead, but you want to predict, say $[t+k, t+m]$ from time $t$.